# How to store multiple dates in mysql when starting date is known

Tags: mysql, database, store

I am building a Scheduler in which it has 3 buttons -

```
Set A Reminder
Schedule Daily
Schedule Weekly
```

I have implemented the functionality of first button i.e details are successfully saved in mysql db and accordingly notification will pop up.

But I have a query that how to write a sql query for 2nd and 3rd button given the current date .

I have implemented 2nd functionality like

```
INSERT INTO schedulerDetails( userId,time) VALUES
( 'ankur',STR_TO_DATE('10/24/11 10:00 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') , ( 'ankur',    STR_TO_DATE('10/25/11 10:00 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p'),
( 'ankur', STR_TO_DATE('10/26/11 10:00 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')), ( 'ankur',    'STR_TO_DATE('10/27/11 10:00 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')),
```

like this for all the seven days. But this solution is not feasible for this and also for 3rd button functionality. I want that if user has selected weekly button than except the time column all other fields automatically get copied and I do not have to mention ankur again and again and neither the date manually. Is there any way that the columns which are same gets copied in all rows and date is automatically generated for rest next 6 days based on today date.
Is there any other way to perform the same thing while writing less code.

Comment: @Strawberry No. what is the issue in string them as String.

Comment: @Strawberry done editing. If the results can be easily achieved after converting them to date I have no issues. Actually I am using hibernate to generate tables with spring so had to made all the changes from configuration to model class . But now it has been done.

Comment: @Strawberry I want that if user has selected weekly button than except the time column all other fields automatically get copied and I do not have to mention ankur again and again and neither the date manually. Is there any way that the columns which are same gets copied in all rows and date is automatically generated for rest next 6 days based on today date.

Comment: @Strawberry done. Do you have any kind of solution for this then plz let me knw

Comment: So all events have a start date (the date on which the event first occurs), a recurrence (either daily or weekly), and a duration (the date of last of occurrence) - which can be null for events which reoccur indefinitely. That's all that you need to store, I think.

Comment: @Strawberry can you write a sql query for this

Comment: The question is too broad. The SQL could simply be `SELECT start_date, end_date, reoccurrence_type FROM events;` but the complexity lies in how that result intersects with the array of dates that comprise your calendar, typically rendered as a day, a week, or a month, in application code.